# Python - Taking a picture of the current window

Tags: python

I had an idea for a program I want to write for my boss at work. My idea was that I was going to load a template into python, run through a .txt file and fill the template with the corresponding information using the graphics library.

My only problem is I don't know how to save the final result. Some of my colleagues in a python class I took a year ago did it and now I regret not asking how... Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenum for this purpose.

Selenium using a webdriver provides the facility to take screenshots!

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
# code goes in here
driver.save_screenshot(title+".png")
```

I believe this will serve your purpose!
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

TO take screenshots you can use `pyscreenshot` module.

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
im=ImageGrab.grab()
im.show()
```

Here im variable is the image of the screenshot
Source: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyscreenshot

Comment: Thank you guys for this... and the -4 rep. I'll make sure to search harder next time.